# JSON Queries - Failed to execute

Tags: json, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

So, I am trying to execute a query using ArcGIS API, but it should match any Json queries. I am kind of new to this query format, so I am pretty sure I must be missing something, but I can't figure out what it is.

[This page](https://services.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basisregistraties/BAG/MapServer/4/query) allows for testing queries on the database before I actually implement them in my code. Features in this database have several fields, including `OBJECTID` and `Identificatie`. I would like to, for example, select the feature where Identificatie = 1. If I enter this in the `Where` field though (`Identificatie = 1`) an error `Failed to execute` appears. This happens for every field, except for `OBJECTID`. Querying where `OBJECTID = 1` returns the correct results. I am obviously doing something wrong, but I don't get it why `OBJECTID` does work here. A brief explanation (or a link to a page documenting queries for JSON, which I haven't found), would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Identificatie`, along with most other fields in [the service you're using](https://services.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basisregistraties/BAG/MapServer/4), is a string field. Therefore, you need to use single quotes in your `WHERE` clause:

```
Identificatie = '1'
```

Or to get one that actually exists:

```
Identificatie = '1714100000729432'
```

`OBJECTID = 1` works without quotes because it's a numeric field.

[Here's a link to the correct query](https://services.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basisregistraties/BAG/MapServer/4/query?where=Identificatie+%3D+%271714100000729432%27&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=html). And [here's a link to the query with all output fields included](https://services.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basisregistraties/BAG/MapServer/4/query?where=Identificatie+%3D+%271714100000729432%27&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=html).

Comment: I see now. Since most fields have numerical contents I assumed they had been formatted that way too, but they are indeed strings. Works like a charm now, thank you!